# partition by sequential dates postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, partition, gaps-and-islands

I have PersonId and his special days.
I need partition this dates to periods.

Current table:

```
+----------------+-------------+
|EmployeePosition|DeviationDays|
+----------------+-------------+
|1925            |2021-09-06   |
|1925            |2021-09-08   |
|1925            |2021-09-09   |
|1925            |2021-09-21   |
|1925            |2021-09-22   |
|1925            |2021-09-23   |
|1925            |2021-10-07   |
|1925            |2021-10-08   |
+----------------+-------------+
```

Table what i need:

```
+----------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|EmployeePosition|DateStart    |DateEnd      |CountDays    |
+----------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|1925            |2021-09-06   |2021-09-06   |1            |
|1925            |2021-09-08   |2021-09-09   |2            |
|1925            |2021-09-21   |2021-09-23   |3            |
|1925            |2021-10-07   |2021-10-08   |2            |
+----------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Sequential dates should be union to "periods",

Thanks for any help

Comment: Have a look at https://blog.jooq.org/10-sql-tricks-that-you-didnt-think-were-possible/. #4 does what you're looking for.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: – Bill Jetzer so much thanks!!! this is exactly what you need