# How to form groups of consecutive dates allowing for a given maximum gap?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

Given a table like:

| person_id | contact_day | days_last_contact | dash_group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015-02-09 |  | 1 |
| 1 | 2015-05-01 | 81 | 2 |
| 1 | 2015-05-02 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2015-05-03 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2015-06-01 | 29 | 3 |
| 1 | 2015-08-01 | 61 | 4 |
| 1 | 2015-08-04 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 2015-09-01 | 28 | 5 |
| 2 | 2015-05-01 |  | 1 |
| 2 | 2015-06-01 | 31 | 2 |
| 2 | 2015-07-01 | 30 | 3 |
| 3 | 2015-05-01 |  | 1 |
| 3 | 2015-05-02 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2015-05-04 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2015-06-01 | 28 | 2 |
| 3 | 2015-06-02 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2015-06-06 | 4 | 3 |

See also [DB Fiddle example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3SqXjPAFYihErQ3xWbXhrD/2).

How can I identify streaks of days - consecutive but allowing for a maximum gap?

Original columns in the data are `person_id` and `contact_day`. I would like to partition by `person_id` and the "streak" (group of days close by). My approach so far is to first calculate the number of days since last contact (`days_last_contact`) and then try to use that to calculate the column `dash_group`, which tags rows within the maximum threshold - 3 days in the example.

How can I calculate `dash_group`? I calculate `days_last_contact` by subtracting `contact_day` and it's 1-lag, partitioned by person_id and sorted by date).

```sql
SELECT 
  contact_day - lag(contact_day, 1, NULL) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY contact_day ASC) 
    AS days_last_contact
FROM mydata
;
```

But how can I then use that to group together the rows where `days_last_contact` is below some threshold? (3 days in this example). So, in this example, `dash_group` 2 for `person_id` 1 identify the days May 1, 2 and 3 are close by, but then the next date for that person is June 1, which is too far (29 days since last contact, which is greater than the threshold of 3), so it gets a new `dash_group`. Similarly, `dash_group` 4, groups together August 1 and August 4, because the difference is 3, but in the case of June 2 and June 6 (person 3), the difference is 4 and then they are classified in different groups.

After looking around, I've found for example [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69663228/partition-by-sequential-dates-postgres) where they point to the ['trick' #4 here](https://blog.jooq.org/10-sql-tricks-that-you-didnt-think-were-possible/), which is nicely hacky, but only works for consecutive dates / gapless series, and I need to allow for arbitrary gaps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Counting the gaps (greater than given tolerance) in a second window function forms the group numbers you are after:

```sql
SELECT person_id, contact_day
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE gap > 3) OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY contact_day) AS dash_group
FROM  (
   SELECT person_id, contact_day
        , contact_day - lag(contact_day) OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY contact_day) AS gap
   FROM   mydata
   ) sub
ORDER  BY person_id, contact_day;  -- optional
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=af21693cdc813bf3696acb552913c818)*

About the aggregate `FILTER` clause:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)

It's short and intuitive, and typically fastest. See:

- [For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27572/3684)

It's the classic topic of **"gaps and islands"**. Once you know to look for the tag [gaps-and-islands](/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands), you'll find plenty of related or nigh identical questions and answers like:

- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35389/3684)
- [How to group timestamps into islands (based on arbitrary gap)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55045788/how-to-group-timestamps-into-islands-based-on-arbitrary-gap/55065060#55065060)
- [How to label groups in postgresql when group belonging depends on the preceding line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314132/how-to-label-groups-in-postgresql-when-group-belonging-depends-on-the-preceding/34317232#34317232)

Etc.

I tagged accordingly now.

Answer (score 2):

Using a recursive query:

---

```
WITH RECURSIVE zzz AS (
    SELECT person_id
    , contact_day
    , md.days_last_contact
    , row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY contact_day)
        AS dash_group
    FROM mydata md
    WHERE NOT EXISTS ( -- only the group *leaders*
            SELECT * FROM mydata nx
            WHERE nx.person_id = md.person_id
            AND nx.contact_day < md.contact_day
            AND nx.contact_day >= md.contact_day -3
            )
UNION ALL
    SELECT md.person_id
    , md.contact_day
    , md.days_last_contact
    , zzz.dash_group
    FROM zzz
    JOIN mydata md ON md.person_id = zzz.person_id
            AND md.contact_day > zzz.contact_day
            AND md.contact_day <= zzz.contact_day +3
            AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * -- eliminate the middle men ...
                    FROM mydata nx
                    WHERE nx.person_id = md.person_id
                    AND nx.contact_day > zzz.contact_day
                    AND nx.contact_day < md.contact_day
            )
    )
SELECT * FROM zzz
ORDER BY person_id,contact_day
    ;
```

---

There will probably be a shorter solution using window functions.

The result:

---

```
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 14
 person_id | contact_day | days_last_contact | dash_group 
-----------+-------------+-------------------+------------
         1 | 2015-02-09  |                   |          1
         1 | 2015-05-01  |                81 |          2
         1 | 2015-05-02  |                 1 |          2
         1 | 2015-05-03  |                 1 |          2
         1 | 2015-06-01  |                29 |          3
         1 | 2015-08-01  |                61 |          4
         1 | 2015-08-04  |                 3 |          4
         1 | 2015-09-01  |                28 |          5
         2 | 2015-05-01  |                   |          1
         2 | 2015-06-01  |                31 |          2
         2 | 2015-07-01  |                30 |          3
         3 | 2015-05-01  |                   |          1
         3 | 2015-05-02  |                 1 |          1
         3 | 2015-05-04  |                 2 |          1
(14 rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, we can try to use condition in `SUM` window function.

If we created a suitable index (`person_id` and `contact_day` columns) in `mydata` table we might get better performance for this query.

**Query #1**

So query might be as below

```
SELECT 
  person_id, 
  contact_day, 
  days_last_contact,
  SUM(CASE WHEN days_last_contact <= 3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY contact_day) 
FROM mydata
ORDER BY person_id, contact_day
;
```

if `days_last_contact` needs to be calculated, we can try to calculate it subquery.

```
SELECT 
  person_id, 
  contact_day, 
  days_last_contact,
  SUM(CASE WHEN days_last_contact <= 3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY contact_day) 
FROM (
    SELECT person_id,
           contact_day,
           contact_day - lag(contact_day) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY contact_day ASC) 
        AS days_last_contact
    FROM mydata
) t1
ORDER BY person_id, contact_day
;
```

| person_id | contact_day | days_last_contact | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015-02-09T00:00:00.000Z |  | 1 |
| 1 | 2015-05-01T00:00:00.000Z | 81 | 2 |
| 1 | 2015-05-02T00:00:00.000Z | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2015-05-03T00:00:00.000Z | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2015-06-01T00:00:00.000Z | 29 | 3 |
| 1 | 2015-08-01T00:00:00.000Z | 61 | 4 |
| 1 | 2015-08-04T00:00:00.000Z | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 2015-09-01T00:00:00.000Z | 28 | 5 |
| 2 | 2015-05-01T00:00:00.000Z |  | 1 |
| 2 | 2015-06-01T00:00:00.000Z | 31 | 2 |
| 2 | 2015-07-01T00:00:00.000Z | 30 | 3 |
| 3 | 2015-05-01T00:00:00.000Z |  | 1 |
| 3 | 2015-05-02T00:00:00.000Z | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2015-05-04T00:00:00.000Z | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2015-06-01T00:00:00.000Z | 28 | 2 |
| 3 | 2015-06-02T00:00:00.000Z | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2015-06-06T00:00:00.000Z | 4 | 3 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3SqXjPAFYihErQ3xWbXhrD/3)